# Prisma relation where field not A

Tags: typescript, mongodb, prisma

My goal is to get every TutelageClass where the user is not already registered to the next session.
The solution displayed at the end always shows every TutelageClass.

I'm trying to execute the following query with Prisma :

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.title
FROM a
INNER JOIN ON a.nextSession = b.id
INNER JOIN ON b.id = c.tutelageSession
INNER JOIN ON c.user = d.id
WHERE d.name NOT 'VALUE';
```

Here my tables :
| a (TutelageClass) | b (TutelageSession) | c | d (User) |
| :-: | :-: | :-: | :-: |
| *id* | *id* | *#user* | *id* |
| title | title | *#tutelageSession* | name |
| #nextSession |

My Prisma schema is the following (simplified) :

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model TutelageClass {
  id                   String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title                String

  nextSessionId String? @db.ObjectId
  nextSession TutelageSession?
}

model TutelageSession {
  id         String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId

  registeredStudentsIDs String[] @db.ObjectId
  tutelageClassId       String   @unique @db.ObjectId

  tutelageClass      TutelageClass @relation(fields: [tutelageClassId], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Restrict)
  registeredStudents User[]        @relation("RegisteredStudentsToTutelageSession", fields: [registeredStudentsIDs], references: [id])
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String?

  registeredToTutelageSessionIDs String[] @db.ObjectId

  registeredToTutelageSession TutelageSession[] @relation("RegisteredStudentsToTutelageSession", fields: [registeredToTutelageSessionIDs], references: [id])
}
```

And finally, the code I'm trying :

```
const c = await client.tutelageClass.findMany({
    select: {
        id: true,
        title: true,
    }, where: {
        nextSession: {
            registeredStudents: {
                none: {
                    id: userIdNotRegistered
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s an example which I tried based on your schema file. I created two users and each user is registered to a different session of a class.
User Alice is registered in Math Class and User Bob is registered in Science class.
And the last query gets the classes in which Alice is not registered for, the query seems to be working as expected for me as I get Science class as a result of the query which is correct.

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  log: ['query'],
});

async function main() {
  const mongoUserId1 = '5f9b9b9b9b9b9b9b9b9b9b9b';

  await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      id: mongoUserId1,
      name: 'Alice',
      registeredToTutelageSession: {
        create: {
          id: '5f9a9a9a9a9a9a9a9a9a9a9a',
          tutelageClass: {
            create: {
              title: 'Math',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });

  const mongoUserId2 = '5f9c9c9c9c9c9c9c9c9c9c9c';

  await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      id: mongoUserId2,
      name: 'Bob',
      registeredToTutelageSession: {
        create: {
          id: '5f9d9d9d9d9d9d9d9d9d9d9d',
          tutelageClass: {
            create: {
              title: 'Science',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });

  const classes2 = await prisma.tutelageClass.findMany({
    where: {
      nextSession: {
        registeredStudents: {
          none: {
            id: mongoUserId1,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });

  console.log('classes2', classes2);
}

main()
  .catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });
```

Here’s the output:
[image]

Comment: Link to internal slack conversation: https://prisma.slack.com/archives/CA491RJH0/p1664183762813599